# MySQL count unique customer that purchased an certain item

Tags: mysql

tbl_products

```
+-------+---------+---------+
|  id   |  item   | Customer|
+-------+---------+---------+
|   1   |  Apple  | brad    |
|   2   |  Apple  | alex    |
|   3   |  Apple  | brad    |
|   4   |  Apple  | brad    |
|   5   |  Apple  | tim     |
|   6   |  Orange | brad    |
|   7   |  Orange | steve   |
|   8   |  Orange | alex    |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

How many unique customers purchased Apples?
answer should be:
Apple 3

Comment: And what have you tried so far to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Customer)
FROM tbl_products
WHERE  item ='Apple'
```